# Is there a way to perform lag/lead operations by ignoring NAN values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, lag

I have a dataset that includes date, customer, and a value(magnitude of the event) columns. I want to create a new column called 'last_occurance_date' which is the last time the event happened for each customer. I have a cross table for all customers and dates, so I have a lot of null values meaning that event did not happen on this date for this customer.

I've tried to use group by with shift function but I couldn't ignore the null values where the event did not happen.

Filter out null values -> lag without nulls -> join with table -> ffill works but is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Let's suppose you have this DataFrame:

| Date | Customer | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 10 |
| 2 | aaa | NA |
| 3 | aaa | 20 |
| 4 | aaa | NA |
| 5 | aaa | 50 |
| 1 | bbb | NA |
| 2 | bbb | NA |
| 3 | bbb | 30 |
| 4 | bbb | NA |
| 5 | bbb | 50 |

Output Dataframe should look like this:

| Date | Customer | Value | Last Occurance Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 10 | NA |
| 2 | aaa | NA | 1 |
| 3 | aaa | 20 | 1 |
| 4 | aaa | NA | 3 |
| 5 | aaa | 50 | 3 |
| 1 | bbb | NA | NA |
| 2 | bbb | NA | NA |
| 3 | bbb | 30 | NA |
| 4 | bbb | NA | 3 |
| 5 | bbb | 50 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `groupby` operation on the masked Date:

```
df['Last Occurrence Date'] = (df['Date'].mask(df['Value'].isna())
                             .groupby(df['Customer'])
                              .apply(lambda g: g.ffill().shift())
                             )
```

output:

```
   Date Customer  Value  Last Occurrence Date
0     1      aaa   10.0                   NaN
1     2      aaa    NaN                   1.0
2     3      aaa   20.0                   1.0
3     4      aaa    NaN                   3.0
4     5      aaa   50.0                   3.0
5     1      bbb    NaN                   NaN
6     2      bbb    NaN                   NaN
7     3      bbb   30.0                   NaN
8     4      bbb    NaN                   3.0
9     5      bbb   50.0                   3.0
```